# OpenCL - multiple threads on a gpu

Tags: c++, macos, openmp, opencl, gpgpu

After having parallelized a C++ code via OpenMP, I am now considering to use the GPU (a Radeon Pro Vega II) to speed up specific parts of my code. Being an OpenCL neophyte,I am currently searching for examples that can show me how to implement a multicore CPU - GPU interaction.

Here is what I want to achieve. Suppose to have a fixed short length array, say {1,2,3,4,5}, and that as an exercise, you want to compute all of the possible "right shifts" of this array, i.e.,

```
{5,1,2,3,4}
{4,5,1,2,3}
{3,4,5,1,2}
{2,3,4,5,1}
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

.

The relative OpenCL code is quite straightforward.

Now, suppose that your CPU has many cores, say 56, that each core has a different starting array and that at any random instant of time each CPU core may ask the GPU to compute the right shifts of its own array. This core, say core 21, should copy its own array into the GPU memory, run the kernel, and wait for the result. My question is "during this operation, could the others CPU cores submit a similar request, without waiting for the completion of the task submitted by core 21?"

Also, can core 21 perform in parallel another task while waiting for the completion of the GPU task?

Would you feel like suggesting some examples to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU works with a queue of kernel calls and (PCIe-) memory transfers. Within this queue, it can work on non-blocking memory transfers and a kernel at the same time, but not on two consecutive kernels. You could do several queues (one per CPU core), then the kernels from different queues can be executed in parallel, provided that each kernel only takes up a fraction of the GPU resources. The CPU core can, while the queue is being executed on the GPU, perform a different task, and with the command `queue.finish()` the CPU will wait until the GPU is done.

However letting multiple CPUs send tasks to a single GPU is bad practice and will not give you any performance advantage while making your code over-complicated. Each small PCIe memory transfer has a large latency overhead and small kernels that do not sufficiently saturate the GPU have bad performance.
The multi-CPU approach is only useful if each CPU sends tasks to its own dedicated GPU, and even then I would only recommend this if your VRAM of a single GPU is not enough or if you want to have more parallel troughput than a single GPU allows.

A better strategy is to feed the GPU with a single CPU core and - if there is some processing to do on the CPU side - only then parallelize across multiple CPU cores. By combining small data packets into a single large PCIe memory transfer and large kernel, you will saturate the hardware and get the best possible performance.

For more details on how the parallelization on the GPU works, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652001/9178992